# regex search term in variable

Tags: regex, string, search, var

Do you know how I am able to put the search string inside the RegExp?
Let say if my search term is 'Ame', then I can write

```
v.name.search(new RegExp(/Ame/i)).                //It works  

var search = $("#search-query").val();
v.name.search(new RegExp('/'+search+'/i'          //It doesn't work
```

However if the value 'Ame' was stored in the var 'search', how do I use the var?

```
var search = $("#search-query").val();
if($("#search-query").val().length <1){  
            $scope.hiddenError = true;
            return;
        } 

$.each(json.products, function(i, v) {
     if (v.name.search(new RegExp('/'+search+'/i')) != -1) {              //doesn't work
           $scope.recentGame.push({ label:v.name, value: v.type, link: v.url });
           return;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to build a custom regular expression from a string, you don't include the delimiters `/` or the options. You use the following form of the function constructor:

```
var regex = new RegExp(search, "i");
```

and use that in the `search` method.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate that!!